# how to skip table using HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, asp.net

i wrote an app that take values from a table and manipulat them, my problem is that there is 2 tables before the table i want(without id,class) . i want to skip them and go to the third table . my code:

```
        HtmlNodeCollection tables = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table");
        HtmlNodeCollection rows = tables[2].SelectNodes(".//tr");

        foreach (HtmlNode item in rows)
        {    
         /// my code//

        }
```

i thought the code: table[2] means go to the third table but infact it mean take 3 tables, is there a way to define spacific table or from to tables? (without id or class name in the table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think the below code will help you on this...

```
HtmlNodeCollection tables = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[3]");
HtmlNodeCollection rows = tables.SelectNodes(".//tr");
```

`"//table[3]"` : it defines the 3rd table

Comment: if i do this: HtmlNodeCollection tables = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[3]"); HtmlNodeCollection rows = tables[2].SelectNodes(".//tr"); i get thid error :Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index

Comment: @ogsMC : change your code FROM HtmlNodeCollection rows = tables[2].SelectNodes(".//tr"); TO HtmlNodeCollection rows = tables.SelectNodes(".//tr"); will get work....

Answer (score 0):

You just need to specify the index of the table: HtmlNodeCollection tables = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[2]");

Comment: if i do this:              HtmlNodeCollection tables = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[2]");
            HtmlNodeCollection rows = tables[2].SelectNodes(".//tr");
i get thid error :Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

Comment: If you intend to get the third table you will do this only in your xpath query.
You don't have to specify it in this line:
tables.SelectNodes(".//tr");